# Limit the times users can work with my web app

Tags: language-agnostic

I have a simple web app and I would like to limit the times the user can use my app.

Basicly my app generate some report, so I should count how many report they generated in a month.

I was thinking to create a database table where I store the month and the times count of generated report. Each time user generate a report the script check the month to see if is current month and if is current month it increase the times count. Instead if the current month is different it sets the times count to 0.

Is this a good start point? or i should make something better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If it is current month and if is current month it increase the times count. Instead if the current month is different it sets the times count to 0.

You will miss out on the edge case when a user generates reports after a period of approx 1 year. Say he generates 5 times report in October 2012 , and next tries to generate a report in October 2013, then his counter starts from 5 instead of 0 in the current scenario.

I am assuming you are taking two fields to store the information currently (one field for month, the other for count).

So now, Including the year, you will need 3 fields.

To optimise on number of fields, you can instead save the date for the 1st day of current month (2 fields total).

To further reduce the number of fields, you can save the information in one field - save an integer, say `yymmxx`, where yy is the year, mm is the month, and xx is the number of attempts.

In this approach, to find out previous number of attempts, you will need to do `field % 100`, and to match if the current month is same, you will need to check for `field/100 == yy*100 + mm`